# Suppressing output with the Exec task in msbuild

Tags: msbuild

I'm running a command using the msbuild "Exec" task. However I do not want the stdio output generated from the command to appear in the console, is there anyway to suppress it?

Maybe something along the lines of using the Exec task to call "cmd.exe" with my command exe is a target , and then using ">" to redirect the output somewhere else. (However I'm unable to get this solution to work).

i.e.

```
<Exec Command="cmd.exe sqlplus.exe  $(someCommandSpecificSettings) &lt; test.txt"/>
```

Any suggestions to get my example to work or alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured it out ... cmd.exe required a /c argument to work for what I wanted i.e.:

Also, it should be `&gt;` instead of `&lt;`

```
<Exec Command="cmd.exe /c sqlplus.exe  $(someCommandSpecificSettings) &gt; test.txt"/>
```

Answer (score 17):

The best way to suppress Standard Output and Standard Error Output from [Exec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124731(v=VS.110).aspx) tasks or any task that inherits from [ToolTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.tooltask(v=vs.110).aspx) is to lower the importance of the output. That way if you're debugging your build, these output won't be completely hidden because you're redirecting them to nul.

```
<Exec Command="sqlplus.exe" StandardOutputImportance="low" StandardErrorImportance="low"/>
```

Comment: This is a great answer! Works both on Windows and *nix, and is exactly what I need - suppress output in the normal case, but keep it for debugging purposes. Awesome!

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks.

Comment: This answer was hard to find but is very handy.  I wanted to note for those looking to use the ConsoleToMsBuild property that this answer is how you can get console output into MSBuild variables, without having that console output show up in the (non-verbose) build output.

Answer (score 10):

Just for your information :

- > ( `&gt;`) redirect the output to the file you specified after (overwritten if needed)
- > > append the output to the file you specified after (not overwritten)
- < redirect the standard INPUT to your command (basically pass the content of the file after to your command)

With your code, you create (once) and replace each time a test.txt file. Instead of using a filename, you can use NUL that means redirect to nowhere. This will not create the file (which could be huge in some case) :

```
<Exec Command="cmd.exe /c sqlplus.exe  $(someCommandSpecificSettings) &gt; NUL"/>
```

If you want to redirect the errors as well, you use 2> like :

```
<Exec Command="cmd.exe /c sqlplus.exe  $(someCommandSpecificSettings) &gt; NUL 2&gt;errors.txt"/>
```

Also note that you can redirect the stderr to stdout using 2>&1, thus

```
> NUL 2>&1
```

will redirect everything to nowhere.

Hope this clarifies your mind ^^

Comment: **Warning:** Redirecting to `NUL` only works on Windows, and not on Linux.

Comment: While this answer does work on Windows, consider [@Xacron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48306223/177710) if you simply want to suppress the output in the "normal" case but still keep it visible during debugging with `diagnostic` verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Exec Command="cmd.exe sqlplus.exe  $(someCommandSpecificSettings) &lt; test.txt >nul"/>
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work .. I still get a "The system cannot find the file specified" message.

Comment: That message is telling you it couldn't find 'test.txt' to read as input, since you got the `&lt` wrong.